# Overwriting partitions in BigQuery table using dataflow

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Im looking for a solution to overwrites multiple partition in BigQuery table using dataflow pipeline

I have a pipeline that write data to bq table:

```
input_data = [
    {"Date": "2023-01-01", "value": 2},
    {"Date": "2023-01-02", "value": 2}
]
schema = {
    "fields": [
        {"name": "Date", "type": "DATE", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
        {"name": "value", "type": "INTEGER", "mode": "NULLABLE"}
    ]
}
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    (
        p
        | beam.Create(input_data)
        | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            "test_project:test_dataset.test_table",
            schema=schema,
            write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE,
            create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_NEVER,
            additional_bq_parameters={
                'timePartitioning': {
                    'type': 'DAY',
                    'field': 'Date'
                },
            })
    )
```

in bq table  i have:

```
Date, value
2023-01-01, 1
2023-01-02, 1
2023-01-03, 1
```

after running pipeline I got only 2 rows:

```
Date, value
2023-01-01, 2
2023-01-02, 2
```

Im aware that I can overwrite to specific partition without destroying rest of the table specifying partition In a table name:

```
"test_project:test_dataset.test_table$20230102"
```

but this only work for one partition and im looking for solution that will allow me to overwrite multiple partitions at once.

I tried for loop to create multiple WriteToBigQuery for different dates but it will crate to big graph in case of large number of partitions and im looking for another solution

Comment: Is this https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#using-dynamic-destinations what you want?